# Blur div when clicked outside without jQuery

Tags: javascript

After reading a lot of stuff I can't wrap my head around this:

I have a filter list as follows:

```
<div class="filters_list">
    <div tabindex="-1" class="filter_box" id="'mask1.png'" onclick="selectFilter('mask1.png')">
        <img class="filter" id="'mask1.png'" src="pictures/filters/'mask1.png'"/>
    </div>
    <div tabindex="-1" class="filter_box" id="'mask2.png'" onclick="selectFilter('mask2.png')">
        <img class="filter" id="'mask2.png'" src="pictures/filters/'mask2.png'"/>
    </div>

//...
```

And an `img` changed depending on the filter selected:

```
<img class="filter_img" id="filter_image" src="">

function selectFilter(filter_name)
{
    document.getElementById(filter_image).src = "/pictures/filters/" + "filter_name";
}
```

I would like to empty the `src` of the `img` when the user clicks outside the filters list.

```
function blur()
{
    document.getElementsByClassName("filter_img")[0].src = "";
}
```

How can I trigger the `blur()` function without jQuery when one of the filters list element is blurred or clicked outside of?

Comment: Add click event to the document and  check if it's closet element is not `filters_list` then you can remove the `src` of img.

Comment: @randomSoul Thanks random! Which document are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add click event to body and write check to closest `.filters_list` element.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (!e.target.closest('.filters_list')) {
    blur();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onClick event to the document and check if the closest element is not filters_list
if not you can remove the src of the img :

```
document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
   if (!e.target.closest(".filters_list")) {
      blur();
   }
}
```